# Loading more button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I have a general question that I can't seem to find a good answer for. What I'm trying to build is a way to form nested comments.

**comments table**

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    cid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    comment VARCHAR(255),
    username VARCHAR REFERENCES users(username),
    user_id INT REFERENCES users(uid),
    stream_id INT REFERENCES streams(sid),
    cid_reference INT REFERENCES comments(cid),
    date_created TIMESTAMP
);
```

**Query to obtain all comments in a hierarchical view**

```
-- Query to obtain nested comments
WITH RECURSIVE nested_comments AS (
    -- non-recursive term
    SELECT
        cid,
        comment, 
        username,
        user_id,
        stream_id,
        cid_reference,
        date_created
    FROM
        comments 
    WHERE
        -- If cid=1, it prints comment with that id and everything that branches from it
        -- cid_reference IS NULL prints everything
        cid_reference IS NULL
    UNION
        -- recursive term
        SELECT
            c.cid,
            c.comment,
            c.username,
            c.user_id,
            c.stream_id,
            c.cid_reference,
            c.date_created
        FROM
            comments c
        INNER JOIN nested_comments n_c ON n_c.cid = c.cid_reference
) SELECT
    *
FROM
    nested_comments;
```

The above query gives me the level order of all the comments stored in PostgreSQL. The problem I'm currently experiencing comes from a design and scalability aspect. I'm not too sure how I should approach fetching the comments data. One solution I thought of was fetching all the comments all at once and store all of it in the state of the application. Then where the comments are displayed, there would be 10 comments shown at a time with a "Load more" button to show more. Each comment, also has a "View replies" button that when clicked, displays 10 comments and changes to "View more replies" when appropriate. The solution also includes keeping track of the last cut-off was where the comments or replies was.

So for example, let cid and cid_reference represent comment id and reference to the parent comment, respectively. The following shows the structure of the data.

cid=1, cid_reference=null -> cid=2, cid_reference=1, cid=3, cid_reference=1 -> cid=4, cid_reference=3

However, I could see this being a problem with large data sets. The next solution is having the "Load button", "View replies" and "View more replies" button to fetch the data from the database, when needed instead of fetching all at once. The problem is how would I go about doing that? Sorry in advance if this is a silly question. Thanks!

**EDIT: Some more context to my question**
What I'm doing is using Axios to make the API requests and utilizing Redux to update the state of the application. In the React component themselves, all they do is invoke the action creator to get to process started and once the data is fetched, Redux updates the state of the application which thus causes a re-render of the components. Currently, the data is fetched and stored in an JavaScript object. My question is really, if I have 1,000,000 comments, should I load all of them at once, or load whatever is necessary

Comment: Don't think of your application as a way to access your database via a GUI. That path leads to despair.

Comment: What do you mean? I would appreciate some details on your input. :)

Comment: Its a broad subject. Basically, I am saying that you should practice separation of concerns. Think of your user interface design questions ("do I want a load more button?") as orthogonal to how your data is stored, or even that it is stored. The point is that the UI is populated via some data structure provided by another part of your app. That part of your app should provide a data structure in an appropriate way. In other words, define the interfaces (in the conceptual sense, not the syntactic sense) between app components and you will be able to both optimize later, and write cleaner code.

Comment: @AluanHaddad    Hey, thanks for the feedback. What I'm doing is using Axios to make the API requests and utilizing Redux to update the state of the application. In the React component themselves, all they do is invoke the action creator to get to process started and once the data is fetched, Redux updates the state of the application which thus causes a re-render of the components. Currently, the data is fetched and stored in an JavaScript object. My question is really, if I have 1,000,000 comments, should I load all of them at once, or load whatever is necessary.

Comment: I would load what is necessary by performing specific requests to your backend. It sounds like you have a reasonably robust application stack. My comments were made because your question contained a lot of SQL that should not be particularly relevant to the question given.